# LEFT JOIN and handling NULL Values

Tags: postgresql, oracle, join, null

I have two tables.

Table 1:

```
A   B 
------
1   'A'
2   'B'
3   'C'
```

Table 2:

```
   A   C
----------
   2   15
   3   20
```

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT table1.A, table1.B, table2.C
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.A = table2.A
```

The problem arises in the output which is:

```
    A   B   C
---------------
    1   'A'  null
    2   'B'  15
    3   'C'  20
```

Is there a way to get the null as 0, as I have to do an order by on table2.C. Any help is appreciated.

My expected output is:

```
    A   B   C
---------------
    3  'C'  20
    2  'B'  15
    1  'A'  0
```

ps: I tried with IFNULL(table2.C, 0). Didn't work.

Comment: I don't know which DBMS you use, but there is COALESCE(table2.C, 0) on PostgreSQL

Comment: Oh that worked. Thank you so much!! But the row shows up at the beginning. Do you have a suggestion, to put it at the bottom. Am i doing something wrong.

Comment: Check out ORDER BY

Comment: I did order by table2.c but it works for the other columns not this one.

Comment: Ok I got it, I renamed the column table2.C after the COALESCE and then did order by on that. That worked. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Is `NULLS LAST` available to you?

Comment: Yes. Thank You. I didn't have any idea about this one. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be the most efficient solution:

```
SELECT A, t1.B, t2.C
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 USING (A)
ORDER  BY t2.C NULLS FIRST;
```

NULL values are sorted last by default. You can reverse that with `NULLS FIRST`. See:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)